# 5 Stage Datapath - Multi-cycle without pipeline

Tags: pipeline, machine-instruction

I have a 5 stage Datapath with the following steps' times:

```
Fetch 190ps
Decode 120ps
Alu 170ps
Memory 200ps
Writeback 120ps
```

It's asked to calculate how many instructions can be executed in 1us knowing that the processor is working in ***multi-cycle without pipeline*** and that the clock is optimised.

I know that if processor was pipelined and the pipeline was initially empty, the number of instructions would be 4996 by doing:

```
200ps (longest stage's time) -> 1 instruction
1 us                         -> x

x=5000
Nº of instructions = 5000-4=4996
```

Since there's no pipeline on this case what I did was:

```
190ps+120ps+170ps+200ps+120ps = 800ps

800ps -> 1 instruction
1 us  -> x

x = 1250 instructions
```

However the correct answer is 1000 instructions.
Can someone explain me why?

Thank you